# Python's pyserial with interrupt mode

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a device which works on `serial communication`. I am writing python code which will send some commands to get the data from the device.

There are three commands.

```
1.COMMAND - sop 
  Device does its internal calculation and sends below data

  Response - "b'SOP,0,921,34,40,207,0,x9A\r\n'"

2.COMMAND - time
  This gives a date time values which normally do not change untill the device is restarted

3.START - "\r\r" or (<cr><cr>)
  This command puts the device in responsive mode after which it responds to above commands. This command is basically entering <enter> twice & only have to do once at the start.
```

Now the problem which I am facing is that, frequency of data received from `sop` command is not fixed and hence the data is received anytime. This command can also not be stopped once started, so if I run another command like `time`, and read the data, I do not receive time values and they are merged with the `sop` data sometime. Below is the code, I am using:

```
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200)  #Init serial port

port.write(("\r\r".encode()))  #Sending the start command
bytesToRead = port.in_waiting  #Checking data bytesize
res = port.read(bytesToRead)   #Reading the data which is normally a welcome msg
port.reset_input_buffer()      #Clearing the input serial buffer
port.reset_output_buffer()     #Clearing the output serial buffer

port.write(("sop\r".encode())) #Sending the command sop

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    bytesToRead = port.in_waiting
    print(bytesToRead)
    res = port.read(bytesToRead)
    print(res)
    port.reset_input_buffer()

    port.write(("time\r".encode()))
    res = port.readline()
    print(res)
```

Using the above command I sometimes do not receive the value of time after executing its command or sometimes it is merged with the `sop` command. Also with the sop command, I received a lot of data during the `sleep(5)` out of which I need to get the latest data. If I do not include `sleep(5)`, I miss the `sop` data and it is then received after executing the `time` command.

I was hoping if anyone can point me to right direction of how to design it in a better way. Also, I think this can easily be done using interrupt handler but I didn't found any code about pyserial interrupts. Can anyone please suggest some good code for using interrupts in pyserial.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a stab here: Your time.sleep(5) might be too long. Have you tried making the sleep really short, for example time.sleep(.300)? If the time data gets written back between the sop returns you will catch it before it gets merged with sop, but I am making an assumption here that it will send time data back, else there is anyway nothing more you can do on the server side (the python) code. I do believe it won't hurt to make the sleep less, it is anyway just sitting there waiting (polling) for communication.

Not having the having the same environment on my side, makes it difficult to answer, because I can't test my answer, so I hope this might help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using time.sleep(), its preferred to use serialport.in_waiting which help to check the number of bytes available in rcv buffer.
So once there is some data is rcv buffer then only read the data using read function.
so following code sequence can be followed without having any delay

```
while True:
    bytesToRead = port.in_waiting
    print(bytesToRead)
    if(bytestoRead > 0):
        res = port.read(bytesToRead)
        print(res)
        port.reset_input_buffer()
        # put some check or filter then write data on serial port
        port.write(("time\r".encode()))
        res = port.readline()
        print(res)
```